# How to build a Drupal 7 & Colorbox On Page Load Overlay?

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, colorbox

I am attempting to build an on-page-load overlay using Drupal 7 & Colorbox and am stumped. I my JS / JQuery skills are pretty slim and I've hit a barrier. I've created a Block in views and pushing it to my home page. 
I added the .colorbox class manually in my tpl.php file, which is allowing the rest of the colorbox specific classes to be added.
here is the code for my block:

```
<section id="block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block" class="block block-views colorbox init-colorbox-processed-processed cboxElement" style="display:none;">
```

here is my Drupalized jQuery file:

```
/* overlay */
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.initColorboxHP = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    if (!$.isFunction($.colorbox)) {
      return;
    }
    $('#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block', context)
      .filter('.colorbox')
      .once('init-colorbox-processed')
      .colorbox({inline:true,href:"#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block",innerWidth:"600px", innerHeight:"600px"});
  }
};

{
  $(document).bind('cbox_complete', function () {
    Drupal.attachBehaviors('#cboxLoadedContent');
  });
}

})(jQuery);
```

What I expected to happen was the block to be hidden via an inline style definition, which it is. Then my colorbox/jquery would pick it up show it in a nice overlay. Seems like an event handler is not being invoked, but I am not sure how to proceed, so any guidance will be much appreciated. I see some other folks have gotten this working in non-Drupal contexts, but am having difficulty recreating.

I used these resources to get me this far...

http://drupal.org/node/863858

http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/faq/#faq-cookie

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any familiarity with Drupal, but it may just be that you need to add the open property to your colorbox options:

```
{inline:true,href:"#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block",innerWidth:"600px", innerHeight:"600px", open:true}
```

I'm not sure about your situation, but you probably don't need to attach colorbox to an element (are you planning on it being clickable so that you can open it a 2nd time?).  If not, just call colorbox directly.  Replace this:

```
$('#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block', context)
  .filter('.colorbox')
  .once('init-colorbox-processed')
  .colorbox({inline:true,href:"#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block",innerWidth:"600px", innerHeight:"600px"});
```

With this:

```
    $.colorbox({inline:true,href:"#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block",innerWidth:"600px", innerHeight:"600px"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help @Jack, that got me there (sort of...) here is what i did. First, as an exercise, i dumped the drupal stuff (b/c i knew i could cheat and get my script in there w/out the drupal specific stuff. Then I did this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block').show();
$.fn.colorbox({inline:true,href:"#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block",innerWidth:"600px", innerHeight:"600px",open:true});

 $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
            $('#block-views-hp-overlay-hp-overlay-block').hide();
    });

});
```

Which is essentially what i am going for. I am sure there is a more elegant and Drupal proper way, so i'll post that when I figure it out...